# Initializing variables in gekko using the array model function

Tags: optimization, gekko

Defining an array of Gekko variables does not allow any arguments to initialize the variables. For example, I am unable to make an array of integer variables using the m.Array function.

I can make an array of variables using this syntax: m.Array(m.Var, (42, 42)). However, I don't know how to make this array an array of integer variables because the m.Var passed in to the m.Array function does not take any arguments.

- I have a single variable as an integer variable:
  *my_var_is_an_integer_var = m.Var(0, lb=0, ub=1, integer=True)*
- I have an array of variables that are **not** integer variables:
  *my_array_vars_are_not_integer_vars = m.Array(m.Var, (42, 42))*
- I want an array of integer variables: *my_array_vars_are_integer_vars = m.Array(m.Var(0, lb=0, ub=1, integer=True), (42,42))*  **(Throws error)**

HOW DO I INITIALIZE THE VARIABLES IN THE ARRAY TO BE INTEGER VARIABLES???

Error when trying to initialize array as integer variables:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "integer_array.py", line 7, in <module>
    my_array_vars_are_not_integer_vars = m.Array(m.Var(0, lb=0, ub=1, 
integer=True), (42,42))
  File "C:\Users\wills\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gekko\gekko.py", line 
 1831, in Array
    i[...] = f(**args)
TypeError: 'GKVariable' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to pass additional arguments when creating a variable array, you can use one of the following options. Option 1 creates a Numpy array while Options 2 and 3 create a Python list.

**Option 1 (Preferred)**
Create a numpy array with the m.Array function with additional argument `integer=True`:

```py
y = m.Array(m.Var,(42,42),lb=0,ub=1,integer=True)
```

**Option 2**
Create a 2D list of variables with a list comprehension:

```py
y = [[m.Var(lb=0,ub=1,integer=True) for i in range(42)] for j in range(42)]
```

**Option 3**
Alternatively, you can create an empty list (y) and append binary values to that list.

```py
y = [[None]*42]*42
for i in range(42):
    for j in range(42):
        y[i][j] = m.Var(lb=0,ub=1,integer=True)
```

The UPPER and LOWER bounds can be changed after the variable creation but the `integer` option is only available at initialization. Don't forget to switch to the [APOPT MINLP solver](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionApmSolver) for integer variable solutions with `m.options.SOLVER = 1`. Below is a complete example that uses all three options but with a `3x4` array for `x`, `y`, and `z`.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

m = GEKKO()

# option 1
x = m.Array(m.Var,(3,4),lb=0,ub=1,integer=True)

# option 2
y = [[m.Var(lb=0,ub=1,integer=True) for i in range(4)] for j in range(3)]

# option 3
z = [[None]*4]*3
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(4):
        z[i][j] = m.Var(lb=0,ub=1,integer=True)

# switch to APOPT
m.options.SOLVER = 1

# define objective function
m.Minimize(m.sum(m.sum(x)))
m.Minimize(m.sum(m.sum(np.array(y))))
m.Minimize(m.sum(m.sum(np.array(z))))

# define equation
m.Equation(x[1,2]==0)
m.Equation(m.sum(x[:,0])==2)
m.Equation(m.sum(x[:,1])==3)
m.Equation(m.sum(x[2,:])==1)

m.solve(disp=True)
print(x)
```

The objective is to minimize sum of all the elements in `x`, `y`, and `z` but there are certain constraints on an element, row, and columns of `x`. The solution is:

```
[[[1.0] [1.0] [0.0] [0.0]]
 [[1.0] [1.0] [0.0] [0.0]]
 [[0.0] [1.0] [0.0] [0.0]]]
```

Comment: Is there a way to set initial values to the array elements in option 1?

Comment: Yes, use `y = m.Array(m.Var,(42,42),value=0.2,lb=0,ub=1,integer=True)` to set all to `0.2` or set each individually in a loop such as `y[i,j].value = random.random()`.

Comment: I don't know why your code returns an error: Exception:  @error: Equation Definition
 Equation without an equality (=) or inequality (>,<)
 (((0+int_v3)+int_v7)+int_v11)(((0+int_v4)+int_v8)+int_v12)]
 STOPPING...

Comment: I needed to use two summations because it is a 2D array: `m.Minimize(m.sum(m.sum(x)))` - I'll update the response.